# Are references to names, proper nouns?

Tags: names, proper-nouns

We all know proper nouns refer to a specific person, place, organization, ect. Are names that do not refer to specific entities still considered proper nouns such as *Samantha* in the example below? If not, is there a term for nouns that are normally proper but are not when used in a general sense?

---

> ***Samantha*** is a feminine given name. ([Source](http://www.example.com/))

Comment: If *Samantha* is a name, than "*Samantha*" is a name of a name, and hence still a proper noun.

Comment: @Tim - As per your first reply, wouldn't 'name of a name' repeat indefinitely then?

Comment: @TimLymington I think the question is not so much about the reference-referent distinction, as about the fact that "Samantha" does not refer to any particular person.

Comment: Why does this matter? What is your purpose?

Comment: A more pertinent question, in my view, is why, if it were not the first word in the sentence, would it be given a capital letter? If it is not a proper noun surely one would write 'Do you like the name samantha?' The fact that we wouldn't write that seems to me to confirm that it is a proper noun.

Comment: @WS2 I'd write 'Do you like the name "Samantha"?' where the 'S' is capitalized simply because it is so in the quoted text. Thus, I would also write 'There is a country named "China" but "china" means porcelain."

Answer (score 1):

> Samantha is a feminine given name.

*Samantha* is a proper noun whether it represents a real person or not. It is somebody's proper name, their first name.

One does not write, "There is a plethora of jennifers in school. Jennifer is a Proper noun.

The name of the room one sleeps in is a bedroom. It is not a proper noun. A city is not a proper noun, but how many Bethlehems are there? (a significant number.)

I don't think there is a way to get around a proper noun.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking about whether generic names like "Samantha" can be considered proper nouns, given that they lack specificity.

I think the distinction between proper and common nouns is more about whether the noun in question is a **name** or not.  So although "China" can refer to either a town in Maine, or a country in Asia, it is still considered a proper noun.  The same goes for "Samantha" – though it lacks specificity, it is still a name and hence a proper noun.

Comment: OP is asking if you should treat "Samantha" is a proper noun when discussing the name itself, such as "there are lots of towns named China".

Comment: @DougM  You are mistaken.  The question asks: "Are names that do not refer to specific entities still considered proper nouns?"

Comment: @DougM Even when using 'China' to refer to tableware I would tend to give it a capital letter. I was once taught (albeit a long time ago) that anything derived from a name should begin with a capital, hence 'George is a Christian', 'My favourite festival is Christmas', 'I love Shakespearean tragedy', etc.